# What's wrong with this bisection search algorith?

Tags: python, bisection

I've got an assignment for my MITx CS class and I am stuck on the following problem:

> The following variables contain values as described below:
>
> balance - the outstanding balance on the credit card
>
> annualInterestRate - annual interest rate as a decimal
>
> To recap the problem: we are searching for the smallest monthly
>   payment such that we can pay off the entire balance within a year.
>   What is a reasonable lower bound for this payment value? $0 is the
>   obvious anwer, but you can do better than that. If there was no
>   interest, the debt can be paid off by monthly payments of one-twelfth
>   of the original balance, so we must pay at least this much every
>   month. One-twelfth of the original balance is a good lower bound.
>
> What is a good upper bound? Imagine that instead of paying monthly, we
>   paid off the entire balance at the end of the year. What we ultimately
>   pay must be greater than what we would've paid in monthly
>   installments, because the interest was compounded on the balance we
>   didn't pay off each month. So a good upper bound for the monthly
>   payment would be one-twelfth of the balance, after having its interest
>   compounded monthly for an entire year.
>
> In short:
>
> Monthly interest rate = (Annual interest rate) / 12.0 Monthly payment
>   lower bound = Balance / 12 Monthly payment upper bound = (Balance x (1
>   + Monthly interest rate)12) / 12.0
>
> Write a program that uses these bounds and bisection search (for more
>   info check out the Wikipedia page on bisection search) to find the
>   smallest monthly payment to the cent (no more multiples of $10) such
>   that we can pay off the debt within a year. Try it out with large
>   inputs, and notice how fast it is (try the same large inputs in your
>   solution to Problem 2 to compare!). Produce the same return value as
>   you did in Problem 2.

Now, this is what I've been able to come up with but it actually generates a wrong output. I have no idea what's going on wrong with this code:

```
#------------Defined variables---------------#
balance = 999999
annualInterestRate = 0.18
#------------Defined variables---------------#


monthlyInterestRate = annualInterestRate / 12.0
monthlyPaymentLower = balance / 12
monthlyPaymentUpper = (balance * (1 + monthlyInterestRate)**12) / 12.0
month = 1
total = 0

while (total < balance) and month < 13:
    pay = (monthlyPaymentLower + monthlyPaymentUpper) / 2
    total += pay
    if total < balance:
        monthlyPaymentLower = pay
    elif total > balance:
        monthlyPaymentHigher = pay
    month += 1
    if month == 13:
        total = 0
        month = 1
print 'Lowest Payment: ' + str(round(pay, 2))
```

Help?

Like always, not looking for a complete solution or the source code, just drop some hints on where I've gone wrong. (I always get negative votes. :/ )

Comment: The first hint: debugger may be very helpful if you need to understand what's going on.

Comment: No, I completely understand what's happening there, I've written a bisection algorithm before, but this time, I don't what has gone wrong.

Comment: did you take a look at the related questions?

Comment: Yup, but like I've said before, I don't wanna copy paste someone else's code, I wanna solve my problems by _myself_.

Comment: Show expected results. btw: "MITx 6.00.1x Introduction to Computer Science and Programming Using Python" ?

Comment: Ya, that was my first line. :D

Comment: 1) http://postimg.org/image/wyer8kpdd/   2) http://postimg.org/image/dzdt2etab/

Comment: My friend signed up to this class so I signed up too to see what homeworks he has :)

Comment: Now I'm doing "problem 2". There are "Test Cases" on page to test code on local computer before you send it.

Answer (score 0):

In place

```
total += pay
```

you have to count balance for 12 mount like in problem 2

```
for month in range(12):
  balance = balance - pay
  balance = balance + monthlyInterest
```

than you have to compare `balance` with `0` and change `monthlyPaymentLower` or `monthlyPaymentUpper`

You have to compare `monthlyPaymentLower` to `monthlyPaymentUpper` to see if you can finish

```
if monthlyPaymentUpper - monthlyPaymentLower < 0.001 :
    print "now I can finish searching"
```

---

Of course in this situation you will have to change more things in your code :)